# Selection command changes to lower case in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selection, vbe

When my colleague writes a macro with the `Selection` reference in it, for some reason it changes the word `Selection` to a lower case `s` and stops it from working.

Example:

```
Selection.Copy
```

changes to

```
selection.Copy
```

Could someone advise what is happening please? I would guess its his settings somewhere, as he has not previously written any macros.

Comment: He might have declared a variable called `selection` somewhere (public).

Comment: Or he recorded a macro called "selection". Just search his open workbooks' macros for the word selection. Maybe in the Personal.xlsb.

Comment: The error message might be helpful as well.

Comment: See [Avoid re-purposing the names of Properties or Methods as your variables](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/13075/avoid-re-purposing-the-names-of-properties-or-methods-as-your-variables)

Comment: Application.Selection.Copy

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The VB Editor will auto-capitalize according to the casings of the names your code uses for Variables, Sub-Routines and other types, and it will capitalize with roughly the same order as the scopes to a type.

You can resolve the problem by finding any variables called `selection` and changing the casing to `Selection`. If you can't find any, try temporarily *adding* a variable called `Selection`, and all of the in-scope casings will change.

For example, if you define a variable called `workshEEts`, notice that using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` will use the same casing:

```
Dim workshEEts As Workbook
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.workshEEts.Count
```

But there's also a glitch in the editor, because it cache's the names even *after* you delete one. For example, if you delete the first line from the example above, the casing of the 2nd line remains unchanged, and adding a new usage of `Worksheets` results in the cached casing:

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.workshEEts.Count
ThisWorkbook.workshEEts(1).Select
```

So, how do you clear the cache? Create a new variable, even if only temporarily, with the casing you require, and then all of the scoped casings will be updated:

```
Dim Worksheets
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Select
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense, as when I deleted the macro (he had written a macro containing no commands but labelled 'selection') the selection reference worked but stayed in the same lower case format!  Thanks for all your help!